# Is there a way to query files by file id?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to query files (files.list) by file id's?

I have the file id's and would like to load a bunch of files with a single request.

Comment: No, you can't. As per the [documentaion](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters), there is no `id` parameter to search for. So as @jay-lee suggested you should try with a batch request.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing [a batch request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch) with multiple [files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) requests in it.